# Htaccess and nginx converting

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm converting this htaccess file [htaccess file](http://78.47.159.203/htaccess)

to nginx using

http://winginx.com/ru/htaccess

but don't understand where i should paste result. I have created 
include file

include /etc/nginx/myfile

and pasted file there but when i'm reloading (restarting) Nginx it Fails.

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please paste information here and esp. also the message, why nginx fails to restart. That should be found in some log file, if not emitted directly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect these apache .htaccess converters do not fully utilize the unique features of nginx. I would recommend trying something like this:

```
server {
    listen  80  default_server;
    server_name  _;

    root    /var/www/example.com;
    index   index.php;

    # if the file or directory doesn't exist, serve /index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    # if the request is exactly /sitemax.xml, serve sitemap_xml.php
    location = /sitemax.xml {
        try_files /modules/sitemap/sitemap_xml.php =404;
    }

    # hide regex location in a prefix location to avoid confusion
    # introduced by multiple regex locations
    location /pages-print {
        location ~ ^/pages-print(\d+) {
            try_files /modules/pages/print.php?page=$1 =404;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. I tried paste result from the convertor to nginx.conf and it was mistake. I, instead created file in /etc/nginx/ and named it htac.rules (i think it doesn't matter of how you'll name it).

Then i opened file etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default and in location / inserted include /etc/nginx/htac.rules

so.

in htac.rules i inserted converting result without location / {...}

and, yeah. It solved my problem.

Thanks everyone for helping me.